# popUpContextMenu relative to button when menu would overflow off screen?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am attempting to show an `NSMenu` when a button is clicked to show some sharing options (I can't use `NSSharingServicePicker` because I need to produce the sharable items in the background). I do this through a simple `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)showShareSheet:(id)sender{
    NSRect frame = [(NSButton *)sender frame];
    NSPoint menuOrigin = [[sender superview] convertPoint:NSMakePoint(
        frame.origin.x, 
        frame.origin.y + frame.size.height + 95
    ) toView:self.dataView];
    NSEvent *event = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:
        NSLeftMouseDown
        location:menuOrigin
        modifierFlags:(int)nil
        timestamp:0
        windowNumber:[[(NSButton *)sender window] windowNumber]
        context:[[(NSButton *)sender window] graphicsContext]
        eventNumber:0
        clickCount:1
        pressure:1
    ];
    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:theMenu withEvent:event forView:sender];
}
```

This normally works fine if the window isn't too close to the edge of the screen. When it is, the normal position jumps because there isn't enough space to accommodate for the menu:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4DFS6EO.jpg]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/yeN9dVx.jpg?1]

I somewhat fixed this by determining the overflow:

```
float marginRight = NSScreen.mainScreen.frame.size.width - (self.window.frame.origin.x + self.window.frame.size.width);
float overflow = self.window.frame.size.width + marginRight - frame.origin.x  - theMenu.size.width - 7;
float difference = 0;
if (overflow < 0){
    difference = overflow;
}
```

Then adding `difference` to `frame.origin.x` (actually subtracting it), but it's an ugly fix. My calculations are also off, which is why I need to subtract 7.

Am I overlooking a more efficient way of positioning the menu relative to the button? `NSShaingServicePicker`'s `showRelativeToRect:` method calculated this for me behind the scenes, and din't require me to do any additional calculations to avoid jumping.